# History lost after passing under ZSH

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

I dowloaded yesterday ZSH. Since when I want to find my previous orders with the arrow up, it does not show me anything. Is there a way to find his old history?

Comment: What do you mean, you passed yesterday? You're dead?

Comment: @melpomene
I downloaded yesterday ZSH.

Comment: If you just downloaded ZSH, you don't *have* any history yet. It sounds like you somehow want to import your existing `bash`(?) history into `zsh`, which is a reasonable thing to want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zsh and bash save their history in the file pointed by the variable HISTFILE. Check this variable in bash (or in your former shell) and set it to the same value in zsh.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner. How do you do that? How can I check the variable HISTFILE?

Comment: You can do `echo $HISTFILE` to show the variable. If you want to set it, do `export HISTFILE=<yourfile>`. You can add the last command in your *.zshrc* file to make it permanent.

Comment: You can read [this document](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l16) to have more information about history in zsh.